# How To Dynamically Change My PHP Function Name Using ACF / Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am basically trying to create an option in the backend of my Wordpress theme where I can create custom shortcodes using the repeater field in ACF.

The code currently works as intended when I only have 1 row created as when I create a second shortcode it tries to redeclare the same function which breaks the site obviously.

I want the $name variable to replace 'test' in the function name.

Here is my code:

```
if ( have_rows( 'custom_shortcode', 'option' ) ) :
while ( have_rows( 'custom_shortcode', 'option' ) ) : the_row();

    $name = get_sub_field('shortcode_name');

     function test_shortcode() {

         if ( have_rows( 'custom_shortcode', 'option' ) ) :
            while ( have_rows( 'custom_shortcode', 'option' ) ) : the_row();

                $content = get_sub_field('shortcode_content');
                return $content;

            endwhile;
         endif;

     }

    add_shortcode( $name, $name . '_shortcode' );

endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: There's a fundamental problem with the approach you're taking that could probably be simplified _a lot_, if you could advise _why_ you want the function name to be different.  While technically you could accomplish this with an approach using a PHP class, it doesn't "feel" good.  I'm guessing there's a better way to accomplish what you really want.  Can you expand on what it is you're trying to accomplish ultimately?

Comment: I have no doubt I am trying to do this in a ridiculous way haha!

Basically, all I want to do is have 2 ACF fields in the back end so I can create custom shortcodes when needed for my client websites etc.

Ideally, the fields would be able to decide the name of the shortcode for example: [my_shortcode_name]

Then also the content that the shortcode will return.

I appreciate your time helping me :)

Comment: note: I would like to create these shortcodes using a repeater field in ACF which seems to be where my issues are

Comment: What will the shortcodes do?  And why multiple shortcodes, vs. using shortcode arguments?